# Thumbnail for youtube music songs

Tags: firefox-addon

I'm trying to make a browser extension for Youtube Music Media controls. I need a way to extract the thumbnail of the currently playing song. I know this is possible since i've seen a couple of extensions employ the same concept. Any ideas?

I tried looking at the source but couldn't find the image .